# SMTP error when using $_ENV for credentials in PHPMailer

Tags: smtp, environment-variables, phpmailer

When using hard-coded username / email / password I have no problem getting a message sent with phpmailer. But when I use $_ENV to hide the credentials I get the smtp error as shown here:

```
    2020-09-08 15:50:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 dd45234.kasserver.com ESMTP
    2020-09-08 15:50:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO browsegenres-f3.loc
    2020-09-08 15:50:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-dd45234.kasserver.com250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 102400000250-VRFY250-ETRN250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250 DSN
    2020-09-08 15:50:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
    2020-09-08 15:50:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
    2020-09-08 15:50:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.loc
    2020-09-08 15:50:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-xxxxxxxx.[SERVER].com250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 102400000250-VRFY250-ETRN250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250 DSN
    2020-09-08 15:50:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
    2020-09-08 15:50:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
    2020-09-08 15:50:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
    2020-09-08 15:50:53 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: VXNlcm5hbWU6
    2020-09-08 15:50:53 SMTP ERROR: Username command failed: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: VXNlcm5hbWU6
    SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
    2020-09-08 15:50:53 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
    2020-09-08 15:50:53 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
    SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
    Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

I don't wan to hardcode the credentials. Any idea how to get rid of this error?

Here's the code:

// initiate phpMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

```
            // see config file
            $mailSenderName = $_ENV['MAILER_CONTACT_USERNAME'];
            $masterPassword = $_ENV['MAILER_CONTACT_PASSWORD'];
            $masterEmail = $_ENV['MAILER_CONTACT_EMAIL'];
            $recipient = $_ENV['MAILER_CONTACT_RECIPIENT'];


            try {
                //Server settings
                $mail->SMTPDebug  = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->Host       = 'xxxxxxx.[SERVER].com';
                $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
                $mail->Username   = $masterEmail;
                $mail->Password   = $masterPassword;
                $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
                $mail->Port       = 25;


                //Recipients
                $mail->setFrom('aaa@bbbbbbbbbbb.com', 'aabbcc');
                $mail->addAddress('mmmmmmmmm@bbbbbbbbbbb.com');

                // Content
                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->Subject = 'Message Received (Contact Page)';
                $emailbody =
                    'There is a new message from: <br>' .
                    '==================================== <br>' .
                    $senderName . '<br>' .
                    $senderEmail . '<br' .
                    '====================================' .
                    $message . '<br>' .
                    '====================================';

                $mail->Body    = $emailbody;
                $mail->send();
                // success, show thank you
                $f3->reroute('/contact/thankyou'); //todo
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
            }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug one thing at a time. There's no point in looking at error in your email when you know you know you have a problem before it ever gets that far. PHPMailer  uses whatever you give it, so *you need to be sure you're giving it the right thing*.

You could reduce the code to debug in this case by cutting it back to:

```
var_dump($_ENV);
```

Once you know that you're setting the contents of `$_ENV` correctly (whether from real env vars, from a [dotenv](https://packagist.org/packages/vlucas/phpdotenv) script, your php.ini config, etc), you can *then* start using the values in your email code.

Comment: ok, thanks. var_dumping the first one
___ 
var_dump($_ENV['MAILER_CONTACT_USERNAME']);exit();
___
results in NULL; Why is it NULL? I use it the same way in another file and it just works fine

Comment: Because whatever mechanism you're using to get data *into* your env isn't working. How are you setting those values?

Comment: I have a .env file in the root of project; in the .env I have - in this case for contact - set:___MAILER_CONTACT_EMAIL="xxx@yyyyyyyyyy.com"___ and I call it as shown above. I use this for Newsletter route and it does what it is supposed to do, that's why I don't understand the error.

Comment: I'm currently checking php.ini and what I have set there is: ___Default Value: "EGPCS"___;___Development Value: "GPCS"___;___Production Value: "GPCS"

Comment: .env files are not read automatically. You need something to read them. It’s usual for frameworks to do this for you. Fundamentally it’s the reading of these that you need to fix, not the scripts that expect them to work.

Comment: Those directives just say what order superglobals are evaluated in, not anything to do with what gets put in them.

Comment: I use fat-free framework, their doc says "It could be possible that the PHP configuration is not populating all globals. If for instance the environment variables are missing, then you have to add E to the PHP configuration directive variables_order." I have the "E" added in EGPCS. This is meant, right?

Comment: Yes, if the E isn’t there you won’t get anything in $_ENV, but it still doesn’t affect how data gets in there. I’d go with Dotenv.

Answer (score 0):

After installing dotenv (vlucas) I simply didn't include it correctly in my ContactController. So that's why var_dump($_ENV) always resulted in NULL. I compared my settings with the other route, NewsletterController. The difference is that in this route I query the database and in the models constructor (where the db connection is set) I 'use' the dotenv class correctly, and that's why the $_ENV is filled with data. I simply didn't see it.

So, in ContactController I set:

```
    use \Dotenv;
```

and after initialising phpmailer I added:

```
            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
            
            $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
            $dotenv->load();
```

Difference to Models class (database connection):

```
            namespace Models;

            use \Dotenv;

            abstract class Model
            {
                protected $db;

                public function __construct()
                {
                    $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
                    $dotenv->load();

                    $this->db = new \DB\SQL(
                        'mysql:host='. $_ENV['DB_HOST'] .';port='.$_ENV['DB_PORT'].';dbname='.$_ENV['DB_NAME'],
                        $_ENV['DB_USERNAME'],
                        $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD']
                    );
                }
            }
```

Comment: Glad you worked that out. Would you be so kind as to mark my answer as the answer?